# How to change logo in prestashop 1.7 login page

Tags: themes, prestashop

I am replacing this code

```
<img id="logo" src="{$img_dir}prestashop@2x.png" width="123px" height="24px" alt="PrestaShop" />
```

with this code

```
<img src="img/logo.png" />
```

in the file adminxxxx\themes\default\template\controllers\login\content.tpl

But my logo is not showing.

Comment: why not substituting it from the backend in the theme page?

Answer (score 0):

Because the image file is not there. You are trying to show the image in `adminxxxx\themes\default\template\controllers\login\img\` directory. I doubt that you put your `logo.png` there.

Use variable `{$img_dir}` which is the images folder in your current theme directory and put your `logo.png` there.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image logo.png in the folder img in the root of your engine and try again, or even better, you don't need to change any file, just substitute prestashop@2x.png image with yours and this is it. The image prestashop@2x.png is using only in that place, so you will not break anything